# mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF' in laravel when running command php artisan schema:dump

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I m using Laravel : 8.^0. After a few migrations i m trying to run `php artisan schema:dump` to generate an sql file. But i m getting the below error

```
mysqldump: unknown variable 'column-statistics=0'
mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'

   Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException 

  The command "mysqldump  --user="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_USER}" --password="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PASSWORD}" --host="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_HOST}" --port="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PORT}" --skip-add-locks --skip-comments --skip-set-charset --tz-utc --set-gtid-purged=OFF "${:LARAVEL_LOAD_DATABASE}" --routines --result-file="${:LARAVEL_LOAD_PATH}" --no-data" failed.

Exit Code: 7(Unknown error)

Working directory: D:\laravel

Output:
================


Error Output:
================
mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF'

  at D:\laravel\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:257
    253▕      */
    254▕     public function mustRun(callable $callback = null, array $env = []): self   
    255▕     {
    256▕         if (0 !== $this->run($callback, $env)) {
  ➜ 257▕             throw new ProcessFailedException($this);
    258▕         }
    259▕
    260▕         return $this;
    261▕     }

  1   D:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlSchemaState.php:142e\Schema\MySqlSchemaState.php:142
      Symfony\Component\Process\Process::mustRun(Object(Closure))
                                                                                         e\Schema\MySqlSchemaState.php:145
  2   D:\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Databasonent\Process\Process), Object(Closure))e\Schema\MySqlSchemaState.php:145
      Illuminate\Database\Schema\MySqlSchemaState::executeDumpProcess(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), Object(Closure))
```

I m using a docker mysql container with below mysql version

mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Comment: HI, is this script written by you or build - in ?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: Same problem here for Linux but no problem on Mac. Mac's mysqldump version is  Ver 8.0.23 for osx10.16 on x86_64 (Homebrew) while Linux's mysqldump version is Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)